# Crystal Field Splitting in Octahedral Complex

Tags: physical-chemistry, coordination-compounds

So i was going through my 1st year engineering chemistry textbook as a i have test in about a few weeks. So my textbooks says:

"Repulsion by six ligands in an octahedral complex splits the d orbitals
on the central metal into t<sub>2g</sub> and e<sub>g</sub> levels. It follows that there is a corresponding repulsion between the d electrons and the ligands. If the d
electrons are symmetrically arranged, they will repel all six ligands equally.
Thus the structure will be a completely regular octahedron."

So i understood the first 2 lines. Basically what my understanding says is that in an octahedral complex the ligands usually approach the central metal along the x, y and z axis. So obviously the orbitals which lie along the axis (d<sub>x<sup>2</sup>-y<sup>2</sup></sub> and d<sub>z<sup>2</sup></sub>) will rise in energy which is your e<sub>g</sub> level  than compared to the orbitals which lie in between the axis ( d<sub>xy</sub>, d<sub>yz</sub>, d<sub>xz</sub>) which your t<sub>2g</sub> levels. What i am not able to understand is the part where they say "If the d electrons are symmetrically arranged, they will repel all six ligands equally". The electrons in e<sub>g</sub> level rise in energy because they face more repulsion from the ligands right? so how is it possible that the d electrons will repel all ligands equally? Shouldn't the electrons in the e<sub>g</sub> level repel them more than the electron in the t<sub>2g</sub> level? I even tried to make my self understand by taking an example of a d5 configuration(which is symmetrically arranged) in the presence of a weak field ligand where two of your electrons would be in e<sub>g</sub> and the other 3 electrons would be in t<sub>2g</sub> level, but still I wasn't able to understand how is it that the d electrons are repelling the ligands equally?

Comment: Confusing wordings indeed in your textbook. For first year material, Chem LibreTexts are far more reliable. Read the section of CFT there. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Crystal_Field_Theory/Crystal_Field_Theory

Comment: And please capitalize "i's" in your post. I understand South Asian languages do not have capital letters but still "I" is "I".